# When does $(p - 1)! + 1 = p^a$ for some $a$ hold? [Wilson primes]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime, and $a$ be integer. When does $(p - 1)! + 1 = p^a$ for some $a$ hold?

For example:
$$p = 5 \implies (5 - 1)! + 1 = 25 = 5^2$$
$$p = 7 \implies (7 - 1)! + 1 = 721 = 7 \cdot 103$$

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Apparently $13^2|\ ((13-1)!+1)$ as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Wilson prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_prime) is a prime number $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $(p-1)!+1$. The only known Wilson primes are 5, 13, and 563.

Comment: Thanks. A big surprise for me though.